# Is it possible to use operator overloading in C++ to change the meaning of an (unmodified) included function?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I intend to adjust (or gain info about) the functioning of a program without changing anything to the actual code. I originally hoped this could be done by using the C++ operator overloading functionality, but first tests are not satisfying.

### Concrete

I have a simple function in *sample.c* file:

```
void dunno() {
    int x = 1;
    int y = 4;
    int z = x + y;
}
```

To alter the functionality I create a header file which (in my head) would looked like the following:

```
...

int operator+(int x1, int x2) // this syntax is obviously not allowed by C++?
{
    // Change and gain knowledge here!
    return something here;
}   


#include "sample.c"

...
```

With other words: I try to alter the real meaning of for example two ints that are being added. And most important when the unmodified function tries to add two ints **my** operator overloaded function should be called instead of the standard C int+int...

Sorry guys, it's hard to decently explain what I intend to say.

Comment: You mean you're trying to overload the plus operator for numbers?

Comment: You can't do this. When you overload the `operator+` one of the two parameters has to be a user-defined class/struct. Otherwise the program won't compile. More precisely you get the following error: `error: ‘int operator+(int, int)’ must have an argument of class or enumerated type`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could *potentially sort of* make this work by writing a value-wrapper class for each primitive you want to intercept (or making it a template on the storage type), and then using macros, like so:

```
template <typename T> class Primitive;
template <typename T>
Primitive<T> operator+(Primitive<T>, Primitive<T>);

template <typename T> class Primitive {
    T value;
public:
    typedef Primitive<T> MyType;
    Primitive<T>(T);
    // ...    
    friend MyType operator+<T>(MyType, MyType);
    // etc. etc.
};


#define int Primitive<int>
#include "sample.c"
#undef int

...
```

but this is going to get unimaginably hairy and you really shouldn't do it.

The key thing to understand is that you'd be transforming the code so much by doing this, it's hard to be sure how much the behaviour is changed. Also, it will just break the any headers included by `sample.c` which declare out-of-line functions or variables.

A better approach is probably just to step through the code in a debugger, if you really want to see exactly what it does (or, if suitable, template `dunno` on its data type so you can pass a debugging value type without macro hackery).

Comment: I also was thinking in the direction of macro's to solve this issue. I  will look into it. Thanks!

Comment: I know this does answer your question, but I still strongly suggest you don't do it, and certainly not with non-trivial code. I'm actually slightly ashamed to have posted it at all.

Comment: My main goal is to symbolically execute a file/function without changing any of the content of the function itself. The above solution makes that possible by replacing regular types with my own "symbolical" types. I know this is defined as dirty programming, but I don't see any other method? Nevertheless thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can do that, but only if at least one of the operands is a user-defined type (which means your example with `int` won't work), and if the type doesn't already have a definition for that operator (or you will get multiple definition errors).

Comment: I'm aware it is possible with a user-defined type, but that means modifying my functions. Thanks anyway.